# Boostrap 4 Modal not working on Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Im trying to use one example from https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/ , adding a modal to my navbar , but when clicking nothing happens.

```
<div class="pos-f-t fixed-top header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-toggleable-md">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" (click)="toggleSidebar()">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Calculadora ISDB-Tb</a>
 <!-- Small modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
              ...
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav> 
</div>
```

Comment: are you using `@angular/material`?

Comment: @masterpreenz mmm not sure what is that :/

Comment: If you are not using ngx-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap. You probably forgot to add jquery

Comment: @brijmcq can you give more direct solution please..dont know what you are trying to explain.

Comment: I can't help you with that information. Can you elaborate more on what you've done?

Comment: @brijmcq im just copying the code for the modal, and paste it in my code. so i can have it in my navbar. the navbar is from this template. https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4

Comment: is your app from scratch? or did you use the template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153420/discussion-between-ixam-deirf-and-brijmcq).

Comment: `@angular/material` in the safe implementation of `angular 2 material` in typescript, I personally use it and it works https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: @masterpreenz i dont understand , what should i do with that?

Comment: did you solve your issue ??

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya no :/

Comment: did you try adding jquery ?

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya how can i do that? can you give me an example please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to use angular [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) for using bootstrap with angular as it has components required for angular and without jquery intervention.

Having said that for your question you should install jquery in your project using

```
npm install jquery --save
```

After that you have to include jquery in your project angular-cli under script section

```
"scripts": [  
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
//other scripts
      ]
```

After this in your component you have to declare $ for using jquery functions as

```
declare var $:any;
```

And in your template give an id to your modal

```
 <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="myModal">
```

And call a function when the button is clicked

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm" (click)="openModal()">Small modal</button>
```

And in your component define the function as

```
openModal(){
$('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

Hope this helps.Let me know if any issue pops up

Comment: Also add "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" in scripts array in angular.json

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to include the `bootstrap.min.js` file in the scripts section of `angular.json`:

```
"scripts": [
   "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
   "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also running into the same issue for a couple of days. Finally, I changed the import statement of jQuery from:

`import * as $ from 'jquery';`

to:

`declare var $ : any;`